# Checking if Queue is Empty Uploadify 3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

Using Uploadify 3.2, is there a way to check if an item exists in the upload queue? Most of the methods I found searching online seem to no longer work in the latest versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I managed to figure this out myself using jquery. I just did a count on the number of children of the queue and used that number to determine whether an item had been uploaded to the queue or not.

My code ended up resembling this...

```
if ($("#upload-queue > div").size() == 0) {
    // the queue is empty
}
```

Comment: this is one of the worst maintained packages I've seen on the net recently. It is a great piece of code but I really wish the main author would supply proper materials (e.g. finding out doc methods by clicking individual links every time?)